# Shiro.ini file requires glassfish clean wipe to update

Tags: java, authentication, shiro, glassfish-4

We're working with Apache Shiro for our user authentication on glassfish 4. We've run into an issue where any changes to the shiro.ini file don't properly get implemented. No matter how many times we push, even if we clean and build first, the system acts like it is using the old version of the .ini file. The only fix is to take everything off of glassfish, wipe it clean, and then a new install will work. This solution is obviously untenable, is there something we are missing? I'd like to include more information, but I don't know what else could be affecting this issue.

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, there are a few problems with undeployments leaving behind old resources (due to the way Windows locks open files) which are now fixed in Payara Server.

Comment: I was able to confirm that we're using Windows. I'm a developer that doesn't really touch our OS system, so is Payara Server something that can generally be upgraded to?

Comment: Yep, since Oracle stopped doing commercial support for GlassFish, Payara are now filling the gap. Payara Server is a drop-in replacement, completely free and completely open source. There are docs for [upgrading Payara Server which also apply to GlassFish](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/user-guides/upgrade-payara.html). The best way to do it would be a side-by-side upgrade.

Comment: If you find a problem or bug, you can [raise it on GitHub](https://github.com/payara/Payara) or if you need general advice which doesn't fit StackOverflow's Q&A, [there's a recently set up Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/payara-forum). ***Disclaimer*** I work for Payara.

Comment: Well I'm wondering if I can just rename the shiro.ini file? That was it points to the new reference?