# Cannot setup login with Apache Shiro JDBC but access restrictions are working

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, shiro

**STATUS**

Please only continue reading if you have built a working JSP, MySQL & Apache Shiro. I have paid 50 reputation points and tried to hire 'an expert' in this area and I still do not have a working app.

**--------------------------------------**

I have tried numerous examples and they have got me so far but I am completely stuck.

I cannot successfully login but restrictions that I have applied to files do work.

Example:

- **/addquestion.jsp = user**  # redirects to the login page
- **/questionSetup1.jsp = anon**  # loads the page

I also setup **[users]**

- guest = guest,admin

but that didn't work either.

**UPDATE**

Rebooted machine and guest worked! What is not working is matching credentials to stored credentials.

**END update**

Could you inspect my setup and please tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

**shiro.ini**

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.usernameParam = username
authc.passwordParam = password
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
authc.successUrl = /index.jsp

jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from user where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role from userroles where userID = (select id FROM user WHERE username = ?)

ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = responseablees
ds.password = responseablees
ds.databaseName = evaluationdb
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds

passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 5000

[users] 
guest = guest,admin

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc 
/index.jsp = user 
/questionSetup1.jsp = anon 
/logout = logout 

/addquestion.jsp = user
```

**db entries**

```
username: chris
password SHA-256: 5d7f15f2fce8ddb2dbef5c38be896c238ba7e0a432e396759030a853fa6b1151
```

I used these same credentials in an example I downloaded built by [hakdogan/ApacheShiro](https://github.com/hakdogan/ApacheShiro) and it works so I know the hash is correct.

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <shiro.version>1.3.2</shiro.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>${shiro.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>${shiro.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
    <version>${shiro.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**REQUESTED Stack Trace**

```
Severe:   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Severe:   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Severe:   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Shiro environment
Severe:   Startup of context /responseablees failed due to previous errors
Severe:   Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:6164)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5981)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[Full Trace](https://pastebin.com/1MXQZip8)

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in your shiro configuration. I think its best if i provide a working example and explain curtial parts. The main issues and problems in your shiro configuration are:

- Wrong usage of multiple filter implementations
- Missing securityManager implementation

Let's start from the beginning:

**Login using login.jsp**

Your login formular has to provide elements attributed by keywords Shiro is looking for when you are using the `authc` filter. By default your form data has to include the following tags: **username** (mandatory), **password** (mandatory) and **rememberMe** (optinally). Make sure to wrap everything into a html form and use "POST" to submit your data.

A working implementation for a login.jsp looks like the following:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="login">
    <form name="loginform" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe">
            <label for="rememberMe">rememberMe</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Database Design**

The [JDBCRealm](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.java) has default queries defined for accessing user information from your database (row 73, 78, 83, 88 in the source code). I strongly recommend using these default field names to avoid confusion and abstraction of your code. If your existing company database design prohibits altering existing tables to match Shiros specifications, i recommend creating a view to match the criteria:

```
/*--------------------------------------------
|             C O N S T A N T S             |
============================================*/
/**
 * The default query used to retrieve account data for the user.
 */
protected static final String DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select password from users where username = ?";

/**
 * The default query used to retrieve account data for the user when {@link #saltStyle} is COLUMN.
 */
protected static final String DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select password, password_salt from users where username = ?";

/**
 * The default query used to retrieve the roles that apply to a user.
 */
protected static final String DEFAULT_USER_ROLES_QUERY = "select role_name from user_roles where username = ?";

/**
 * The default query used to retrieve permissions that apply to a particular role.
 */
protected static final String DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_QUERY = "select permission from roles_permissions where role_name = ?";
```

Users

- Table: users (You just need this table for the example)
- Fields: username, password

Roles

- Table: user_roles (You don`t need this table for the example)
- Fields: username, role_name

Permissions

- Table: roles_permissions (You don`t need this table for the example)
- Fields: role_name, permission

**Shiro shiro.ini**

The main issue i see in your code is the confusion with the different filter implementations you use. They are all mixed up. Also you completely skipped configuring your `securityManager` object.

The `authc` filter is a form authetication filter resposible to autheticate users by processing what they posted to the server by a html form. The `user` filter instead allows access to resources if the accessor is a known user. It has nothing to do with users using your application in the first place.

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /login
authc.successUrl = /index
logout.redirectUrl = /login

hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = 500000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
hashService.generatePublicSalt = true

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService = $hashService

passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

dataSource = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
dataSource.serverName = your_server_name
dataSource.user = your_database_user
dataSource.password = your_database_user_password
dataSource.databaseName = your_database_name

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource 
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher

securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm

[users]
# format: username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
;root = secret,admin
;guest = guest,guest

[roles]
# format: roleName = permission1, permission2, ..., permissionN
;admin = *
;guest = *

[urls]
# The /login.jsp is not restricted to authenticated users (otherwise no one could log in!), but
# the 'authc' filter must still be specified for it so it can process that url's
# login submissions. It is 'smart' enough to allow those requests through as specified by the
# shiro.loginUrl above.
/login = authc
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

**JNDI DataSource** (Optional)

It is regarded as a bad practise to define your data source inside the `shiro.ini` since you will be unable to maintain your data sources in case you get more then one source. Also this eases your life in case you work with a CI-Server since it provides one main point to manage your connections. To solve this you have to define a JNDI data source in your webapp/WEB-INF folder. The following example illustrates how to achieve this in a jetty environment using a mysql database driver:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg></Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/TestDataSource</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
                <Set name="Url">
                    <![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://<server-ip>/<schema>?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC]]></Set>
                <Set name="User">your_username</Set>
                <Set name="Password">your_password</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

**Shiro shiro.ini with JNDI DataSource** (Optional)

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /login
authc.successUrl = /index
logout.redirectUrl = /login

hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = 500000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
hashService.generatePublicSalt = true

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService = $hashService

passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

jndiObjectFactory = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
jndiObjectFactory.resourceName = jdbc/TestDataSource
jndiObjectFactory.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
jndiObjectFactory.resourceRef = true

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $jndiObjectFactory
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher

securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm

[users]
# format: username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
;root = secret,admin
;guest = guest,guest

[roles]
# format: roleName = permission1, permission2, ..., permissionN
;admin = *
;guest = *

[urls]
# The /login.jsp is not restricted to authenticated users (otherwise no one could log in!), but
# the 'authc' filter must still be specified for it so it can process that url's
# login submissions. It is 'smart' enough to allow those requests through as specified by the
# shiro.loginUrl above.
/login = authc
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

If you have any more questions related to this issue in particular feel free to ask, i will update my answer accordingly. The example i provided is a working example i created and tested.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer. I created a branch to test your shiro.ini settings and to confirm the form I copied yours. Unfortunately on testing I get "Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /responseablees
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line argument must contain a key and a value.  Only one string token was found." My own branch still allows me....

Comment: ... to login in with my hard coded entries. I know I was missing the securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Do I have to write my own class that extends the JdbcRealm to authenticate users? And if so how does the system know to run it. My apologies my questions are so novice, I'm completely exhausted by this whole thing.

Comment: The Shiro SecurityManager is the core of the Shiro architecture, you don`t need to further specify it since the default implementation already manages everything for you. The JDBCRealm is a realm which provides authentication and authorisation via JDBC calls. It provides default queries but you can override them. No need to extend this class. Is there any more information about this exception? Maybe a full stacktrace?

Comment: I could only add a partial stack trace here (edited question) and I put the full trace here : https://pastebin.com/1MXQZip8
It is failing on SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" which doesn't make a lot of sense to me my branch before your shiro.ini runs.

Comment: Shiro uses SLF4J as a default logger implementation but you have to provide the actual logger binding yourself. Adding the logger binding dependency is sufficient to fix the issue. `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: I added the SLF4J dependency and it now fails on "Severe:   Startup of context /responseablees failed due to previous errors
Severe:   Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started" I checked around and people talk about mis-matched Java versions and Tomcat. I'm using java version "1.8.0_112"
 and I'm using GlassFish. I'm at a loss.
I created a stripped version of the app here "git clone https://christopherloughnane@bitbucket.org/christopherloughnane/shirotest.git" master has your shiro.ini. branch chris has mine. ....

Comment: ... you've already spent so much time on this and I apologise for posting a repo like that. At this stage this is no longer about work, this has become personal. Again thank you for the explanation which I understand perfectly and it makes sense, just not in this awful project I inherited.

Comment: I'm unable to launch the Glassfish server at all, there is a lot of configuration going on. I'm able to deploy your war in a Jetty instance in the Gradle Gretty plugin with no problem though. It might be a Glassfish configuration issue(?!). Unfortunately i'm not a Glassfish expert but i know its basic configuration.

Comment: I'm so sorry and thank you so much for trying out the code. It makes sense if it's a GF issue. 
I found this post mentioning issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378379/shiro-ini-file-requires-glassfish-clean-wipe-to-update I inherited this project, next time I'll just say no. Thanks very much for all your help UnlikePluto :)

Comment: Hi @unlikepluto What version of Jetty did you test on. I added Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320 to my netbeans and my app will not start. I seem to be caught between two incompatibilities but you mentioned you were able to run it using Gradle Gretty. Could you send me your pom dependency set up that worked?

Comment: Sure! I'm using Gradle with the default configuration of the [gretty](https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty) plugin. I didn't configure any diffrent Jetty version. I just applied the plugin and used `gradlew appRun` to run the application. I used the configuration as described in the answer above. Make sure to use the `org.gretty` plugin since the original one from Akhikhl isn't maintained anymore.

Comment: I hired a guy to look at this and he just faffed about and didn't fix it. :(

Comment: Thats unfortunate. When i was looking at your code, i came to the conclusion that you have misconfigured the Glassfish-Server since i'm able to deploy your war in a Jetty environment with no problem. But i'm not a Glassfish expert. What i can offer you is to provide you a full working example including a database in `org.gretty`. I checked the above code once again if there is any issue with it, which is simply not the case.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thanks so much :)
I inherited this project and I found many incorrect configuration settings, I'll look into the GlassFish env. now.

Comment: UPDATE on a whim I changed the hashed password in the database to a plain text pw and I logged in successfully!!! 
I don't know why the hash is not working as it works perfectly in a demo project I tested

Comment: I'm posting this for you as I'm sure you're curious. I based my hashing passwords on this example https://github.com/hakdogan/ApacheShiro which works perfectly on my GlassFish5 server BUT with the same hash setup on my app it does not hass the login.jsp password supplied and instead compares it in plaintext which of course always failed. So for the past 2x weeks this was workings in the db access but failing in the hash compare. FML

Comment: Great to hear this! I never tested your password/hash but used my own instead. :facepalm:

Comment: It's still a puzzle as to why the password wasn't being hashed by the system. It the hakdogan example he wrote his own class to hash the login.jsp password. I'll revisit your solution and see how you setup the hash. What an ordeal :P

Comment: I took a look at the [hakdogan](https://github.com/hakdogan/ApacheShiro) repository, its completly outdated. You should not use the [Sha256CredentialsMatcher](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/Sha256CredentialsMatcher.html) as they do in the example since its deprecated since `1.1`. The Shiro version 1.1 was released in October 2010 but the repository was created 2013, already outdated. This is not a good source for gathering reliable information.

Comment: You should rely on the [PasswordMatcher](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordMatcher.html) object. As shown in my example above as it is the correct and current solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your hashing settings are correct? Try using the command line hasher: https://shiro.apache.org/command-line-hasher.html and see if you get the expected results

Comment: That is fine and works in the demo code that I am using. I see now that my JSP page is not using my ShiroBean to process the filled form. In the demo he uses Java faces and I don't know how to transpose the setup :(

Comment: Take a look at the Shiro JSP tag lib: https://shiro.apache.org/jsp-tag-library.html

Comment: JSP tags work fine and login with shiro.ini defined users work fine but I cannot get it to work with db stored credentials. I know I have to extend shiro and build a class (realm) but I've been unable to find one using jsp. I have a working example using facelets but I haven't been able to transpose the login code. Very frustrating